# Spark - HashingTF inputCol accepts one column but I want more

Tags: python, apache-spark, tf-idf

I'm trying to use HashTF in Spark but I have one major problem.
If inputCol has only one column like this

```
HashingTF(inputCol="bla",outputCol="tf_features") it works fine.
```

But if I try to add more columns I get error message "Cannot convert list to string".
All I want to do is

```
HashingTF(inputCol=["a_col","b_col","c_col"], outputCol="tf_features").
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: You could concat the columns together before using `HashingTF`.

Answer (score 0):

HashingTF takes on input one column, if you want to use other columns you can create array of these columns using `array` function and then flat them using `explode`, you will have one column with values from all columns. Finally you can pass that column to HashingTF.

`df2 = df.select(explode(array(f.col("a_col"),f.col("b_col")))).as('newCol'))`